# Will Microsoft Security Essentials x64 catch x86 viruses and malwares

Tags: ms-security-essentials

I have windows 7 ultimate 64 bit installed on my PC and i have been using Security Essentials for a while. it worked very good for me.
but i noticed that some times when i connect my flash to my some of my friends notebooks which had the 32 bit version of Security Essentials installed, it catch some viruses on my flash.
Is it possible that the 64 bit version of the software unable to catch 32 bit viruses.

Answer (score 6):

It's definitely possible for a 64-bit Windows system to be infected by 32-bit viruses. So long as there is some sort of 32-bit compatibility a computer can be affected by a 32-bit virus.

It's pretty safe to assume that MSE will detect 32-bit viruses on a 64-bit OS because if they didn't then the Associated Press would've stabbed Microsoft in the neck by now.

Comment: Awesome answer! Yes it detects both 32 and 64 viruses.

Comment: then, can i understand from your answer that the 32-bit viruses which get caught on my fiends PCs are not compatible with 64-bit systems

please, excuse my English writing.

Comment: @Hasomaaaa - Yes, 32-bit processes are compatible with a 65-bit operating systme

Comment: *64-bit, not 65-bit. lol

Comment: It even detects DOS malware.